# Python check if a string is a standard US dollar or not？

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some strings which only contains [`0-9`][`,`][`.`]. I need to check if they are in standard US dollar format. The number of the decimal of the string may be `0`, `1` or `2`. Here are some examples whether they are standard or not.

```
14964,022.97 no
110506785.37 no
67,186,673.9697,764,643.17 no
-263,513.52 yes
15,331,312.0 yes
15,331,312 yes
```

Here is how I do it.

```
import re
re.match(r'^-?\d{1,3}[,.](\d{3}[,.])*.?\d{0,2}?$', '15,331,312.0')
```

- `-?` to check if there is a negative sign.
- `d{1,3}[,.]` to match the start of the numerical. Since we may have cases like `26.32`.
- `(\d{3}[,.])*` to match the middle of the numerical.
- `.?` to match cases without decimal.
- `\d{0,2}?` to match `1` or `2` decimals cases.

Here the problem is 3 decimal case `15,331,312.102` which shoule be `False` but return `True` in my code. Because it was matched by `(\d{3}[,.])*`.

Comment: How about begin with _your_ ideas? What have you tried? What edge-cases do you think you might encounter? Also, what is wrong with `110506785.37`? Separating thousand-groups should be optional when showing dollars and cents.

Comment: A regular expression seems like a decent idea.

Comment: @paddy exactly. That's the point. Why can't we use loops, etc. to determine that?

Comment: @paddy Thanks for the advice. I have edited my post, see my edits.

Comment: @Chris I have used regular expression, see my edits.

Comment: Escaping the fullstop character so that it's treated as a literal instead of a wildcard is enough to make this pattern behave as you seem to expect: `^-?\d{1,3}[,.](\d{3}[,.])*.?\d{0,2}?$`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used to solve this.

```py
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '14964,022.97')
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '110506785.37')
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '67,186,673.9697,764,643.17')
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '-263,513.52')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='-263,513.52'>
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '15,331,312.0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='15,331,312.0'>
>>> re.match(r'^\-?\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$', '15,331,312')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='15,331,312'>
```

The trick is using non-matching groups in `(?: ... )` to make the `,xxx` parts before the decimal point optional as well as the decimal point and numeric digits after it.

Using `re.X` may make it easier to see these separate sections within the regex.

```
>>> re.match(r'^ \-? \d{1,3} (?:\,\d{3})* (?:\.\d+)? $', '15,331,312',
 re.X)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='15,331,312'>
```

Comment: What about 3 decimals like `15,331,312.102`

Comment: If that needs to be rejected, then replace `(?:\.\d+)?` with `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` or if it has to be exactly two digits: `(?:\.\d{2})?`